# Regarding exponential in a Banach algebra

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, banach-algebras

Let $A$ be a complex unital Banach algebra. Let exp$(A)$ denote the range of the exponential function on $A$. Now exp$(A)$ lies in the set of all invertible elements of $A$ (denoted by $G(A)$). Can you give an example of an element belonging to $G(A)\setminus$ exp$(A)$?

Comment: In fact $\exp(A)$ lies in the connected component of the identity in $G(A)$, (just because for any $a\in A$  the arc $[0,1]\ni t\mapsto \exp(t a)$ connects $1$ to $\exp(a)$).  So you have examples whenever $G(A)$ is not connected.

Answer (score 6):

Let $A$ be the algebra of continuous functions on a closed annulus, say $U = \{z \in \mathbb C: 1 \le |z| \le 2\}$ and analytic in the open annulus.
$f(z)=z$ is an invertible element of $A$, but it has no logarithm in $A$.

Comment: Nice canonical answer. Of course (as you know) we can shrink the annulus down to a circle and get the same function as an invertible element of $C({\bf T})$ which is not an exponential in $C({\bf T})$

Comment: Can you tell why $f$ does not have a logarithm? Is it because its spectrum contains -1?

Comment: @user580433 No, the key fact is that the spectrum of the element $f\in A$ disconnects the plane, i.e. ${\mathbb C} \setminus \sigma_A(f)$ is disconnected. The obstruction to taking logs is, essentially, the winding number

Comment: @user580433 Note that: $f\in A:= C(\bf{T})$  is invertible iff $0\notin f(\bf{T})$, that is $f$ is a loop in  $\mathbb{C}^*:=\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$.  And $f$ is in the component of $1$ in $G(A)$ iff it is a *contractible* loop in $\mathbb{C}^*$.

Comment: @Yemon Choi Can you give a reference where I can make my concept about log of a Banach algebra element more clear?